# How to list row headers from matrix based on binary value (Excel)?

Tags: excel, list, matrix, excel-formula, binary

I would like to extract/list from a matrix the row headers based on binary values and depending on the column. Basically FROM something like this:

```
Country  Product1 Product2 Product3
Germany      1       0        1
France       1       1        0
Spain        0       1        0
Italy        1       0        1
Belgium      0       1        0
```

OBTAIN something like this:

```
Product1  Product2  Product3
Germany   France    Germany
France    Spain     Italy
Italy     Belgium
```

So basically list the values based on column and binary value.
Better if no VBA is involved.

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in a table named *Table1*, for `Office 365`:

`=T(SORT(IF(Table1[Product1],Table1[[Country]:[Country]])))`

and use the **fill handle** to drag right.